# Spring Data Rest specify default order by

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am new to Spring Data Rest and looks like exactly I want to use to easily expose some existing database tables as restful services. I have managed to get an example working by following this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/). This works but how would I display all rows ordered by a creation date field by default?

I tried adding a findAllByOrderByCreationdateDesc() method which appears as a new search method through the REST interface but I would ideally like to do this by default when all items are displayed.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override the `findAll()` method in you repository interface:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Override 
    @Query("select u from User u order by u.name asc")
    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

But in this case you will lose the ability to use arbitrary sorting (for example: `/users?sort=name,desc`).
And you will have
unnecessary search resource link `/users/search/findAll{?page,size,sort}`

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Unfortunate that I can't override the sort but I guess I can have different search/sort methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are annotations that comes handy in such situations.

- [`@OrderBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html)
- [`@NamedQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html)

But since you using spring-data-rest and you don't want the custom methods to be exposed these annotations wont help much.

For your scenario you can override the default repository behavior by your own custom repositories. Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) official document.